# Error Handling related to WorkBooks.OpenText Command

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a standard Workbooks.OpenText function however when I hit cancel, it debugs into my code, which I don't want. Instead I want an error handler, so that if I hit cancel, an error box appears stating "No File Selected". I could not figure out how to put in a hook recognizing this OpenText got cancelled.

```
 Set myfile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=myfile, DataType:=xlDelimited, 
 Origin:=xlWindows, Other:=True, OtherChar:=","
```

Comment: I don't understand "... when I hit cancel, it debugs into my code ...". When I use `OpenText` the file opens and there is no opportunity to cancel.

Comment: oops; I added the previous line which had a FileDialog open. Essentially, what is happening is during the standard Excel File Dialog, when I hit cancel, it debugs into the program. I want the user to see an error message when they hit cancel to the File Dialog "Open File" Excel option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        ' TODO configure file dialog
        ' .AllowMultiSelect = ???
        ' .Filters = ???
        ' ...

        If .Show = -1 Then
            ' TODO code to handle FileDialog OK button
            ' Depending on settings user may be able to select multiple items
            For Each vrtSelectedItem in .SelectedItems
                Debug.Print vrtSelectedItem 
                ' Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=vrtSelectedItem, ...
            Next vrtSelectedItem 
        Else
            ' TODO code to handle FileDialog Cancel button
            Debug.Print "user hit cancel"
        End If
    End With

    Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hope that helps